# Need help writing a query of people who didn't make orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a question (Based off of the AdventureWorks 2019 database):

1. Write a query that displays information about customers who did not place any order.
   If the client does not have FirstName and LastName, display 'Unknown' for both

So far I have this:

```sql
Select c.CustomerID, 
       p.LastName, 
       p.FirstName
from Person.Person p join sales.Customer c
on p.BusinessEntityID = c.CustomerID
order by c.CustomerID asc
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please try to replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Comment: Do a left join for the 2a requirement and add a filter checking customerid as null, This will  will give information of customers who have not placed a order. For 2b use case statement like  `case when p.firstname is null then 'unknown' else p.firstname end` and similarly for last name.

Comment: @Sergey `NOT EXISTS` probably the more obvious and more performannt method

Comment: @Nadeem what do you mean to add a filter? and can you give me an example for when using 'case when'?

Comment: Agreed @CharlieFace NOT EXISTS is the correct approach here.

Comment: i think you are querying the wrong table, there should be a table of actual sales

Comment: @Ajsrise current query is fetching all customers. You need to apply where not exist to orders table which will fetch you the customers with no order. for 2b instead of just writing p.firstname, p.lastname use the case statement in both as I stated earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this out an AdventureWorks2019 instance, and it gives the requested 701 record result along with handling the criteria `If the client does not have FirstName and LastName, display 'Unknown' for both`:

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID
    ,CASE WHEN p.FirstName IS NULL AND p.LastName IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE p.LastName END AS LastName
    ,CASE WHEN p.FirstName IS NULL AND p.LastName IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE p.FirstName END FirstName
FROM 
    Sales.Customer AS c 
    LEFT JOIN Person.Person AS p ON c.PersonId = p.BusinessEntityID 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM 
                    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS ord
                WHERE 
                    ord.CustomerID = c.CustomerID) 
ORDER BY 
    c.CustomerID
```

Comment: This is perfect. I continued to work on this on my own with the help of everyone here, and it seems that I needed to use case, left join instead of inner, and not exists (like all of you suggested). I got closer, but still didn't fix the kinks until I saw @trenton-ftw answer. We are learning so much so fast ( in my course) that remembering everything is a challenge in itself lol. Thank you everyone!